# Cannot compile contract with nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Everything was working fine until today that when I try to use `readFileSync` it gives me `[Function]` for every kind of file. In my example when I try to compile the contract it gives me

'Error parsing input JSON: * Line 1, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n'

```
> code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString
[Function]

> compiledCode = solc.compile(code)
{ errors: [ 'Error parsing input JSON: * Line 1, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n' ] }
```

I reinstall nodejs and npm but still I get the same error. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **returns** a function:

```
fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString
```

while this **calls** the function:

```
fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString();
```

and returns not the function but the value returned by the function.

What your code did was saving the reference to the *function itself* in the `code` variable and passing it to the `solc.compile()` which expected a string and implicitly converted the function to a string, which in turn resulted in getting the function's source code and trying to parse it, which failed.